# Kubernetes API server - Connection refused

Tags: linux, sockets, kubernetes

```
E1013: 02:14:27:232417 1 request.go:977] Unexpected error when reading response body read tcp 10.159.64.140:48306 -> 10.129.86.88:443: read: connection: reset by peer

Get "https://10.129.86.88:443.api/v1/namespaces" dial tcp: 10.129.86.88:443 connect: connection refused
```

Above error is encountered **intermittently** (not consistent)

---

Based on existing SO answers, we already verified that:

Certificate is up to date, no firewall access issue, ports are open.

---

K8s cluster with API server(`10.129.86.88`) has 80 namespaces(`kubectl get ns`)

Apart from backend app namespace, we also have one specific namespace (among those 80 namespaces) with a Pod that performs kubernetes cluster monitoring by talking to API server (`10.129.86.88`), regularly.

---

Is Kubernetes API server having backlog of pending connections?

How to stabilise working of Kube API server?

Comment: API server logs should have something about the error, it might be restarting

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community?

Comment: @FariyaRahmat Yes it did. Too mnay network connections for API sever